# Run Kaniko in Jenkins Slave

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, kaniko

I want to run the kaniko as a slave in jenkins . My pipeline is running on the docker plugin and how can I set the gcr credentials with the kaniko.

I want to upload GCR credentials to the Jenkins Master server .

My pipeline groovy is shown as below :

```
node("kaniko-jnlp") {
stage('Building Stage') {
  git 'https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-jnlp-slave.git'

      sh ''' /kaniko/executor -f `pwd`/Dockerfile -c `pwd` --insecure- 
               skip-tls-verify --cache=true 
             --- destination=gcr.io/project/project:v1 '''
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using Kaniko to build images and push to a private repo. My Kaniko docker image uses a Kubernetes `pull-secret` for authentication, but you should be able to use the following code:

```
stage('Kaniko') {
        environment {
            ARTIFACTORY_CREDS = credentials('your-credentials')
        }
        steps{
            sh "echo ********** EXAMPLE APP **********"
            container(name: 'kaniko', shell: '/busybox/sh') {
              withEnv(['PATH+EXTRA=/busybox']) {
                  sh '''#!/busybox/sh
                  /kaniko/executor --context `pwd` --cleanup --dockerfile=your/Dockerfile --build-arg ARTIFACTORY_USER=$ARTIFACTORY_CREDS_USR --build-arg ARTIFACTORY_PASS=$ARTIFACTORY_CREDS_PSW --destination=your.docker.repo/team/image:tag
                  '''
              }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I run my whole pipeline encapsulated inside a pod, here how I use Kaniko:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      yaml """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    jenkins: worker
spec:
  containers:
  - name: kaniko
    image: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    command: ["/busybox/cat"]
    tty: true
    volumeMounts:
      - name: dockercred
        mountPath: /root/.docker/
  volumes:
  - name: dockercred
    secret:
      secretName: dockercred
"""
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Stage 1: Build with Kaniko') {
      steps {
        container('kaniko') {
          sh '/kaniko/executor --context=git://github.com/repository/project.git \
                  --destination=repository/image:tag \
                  --insecure \
                  --skip-tls-verify  \
                  -v=debug'
        }
      }
    }  
  }
}
```